# SQLSERVER 2008 R2 Using filtered Indexes

Tags: filtered-index

Is it true, that QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is to be set to ON when using filtered Index ?
I know it has to be so when using indexed views or index on computed columns.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx):

> ```
> Required SET Options for Filtered Indexes...
> SET options       Required value
> QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
> ```
>
> If the SET options are incorrect, the following conditions can occur:
>
> The filtered index is not created.
>
> The Database Engine generates an error and rolls back INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statements that change data in the index.
>
> Query optimizer does not consider the index in the execution plan for any Transact-SQL statements.